# Create Coloured Electron Pairs in chemfig

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, chemfig

I'm trying to create coloured electron pairs similiar to the picture below.

[image: Picture with red Lewis electrons]

However, when I try to recreate this example, I get black dots surrounded by red for the electron pairs.

```
\documentclass[border=1pc]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig{R-{\charge{90={\color{red}\:},-90=\textcolor{red}{\:}}{O}H}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've searched previous answers and they all use the `\lewis`  macro. I don't want to take this approach since in the latest chemfig documentation, it states that both the `\lewis` and `\Lewis` macros are no longer supported and will be removed soon, and in their place, the `\charge` and `\Charge` macros should be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to in the documentation (see section 8.3  Lewis formula, page 33-34), the color of electron pairs can be changed using `.style=...`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1pc]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}  
     \chemfig{R-\charge{[{.style={draw=red,fill=red}}]90={\:},-90=\:}{O}H}
\end{document}
```